# FCM for Tizen Werable Web Application

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I am working on **Tizen** Wearable **Standalone** Web application and Would like to integrate Firebase to incorporate Notifications Feature. I followed all the steps provided by firebase using Javascript. But I am unable to get the Token and ended up with the below error:

```
Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The URL protocol of the current origin 
('file://') is not supported."
code: "messaging/failed-serviceworker-registration"
message: "Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. 
Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The URL protocol of the current origin 
('file://') is not supported. (messaging/failed-serviceworker-
registration)."
stack: (...)
```

I tried

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
console.log("success")
firebase.messaging().useServiceWorker(registration)
// Registration was successful
console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ',registration.scope);
// registration.pushManager.subscribe({
console.log('Registration was successful1');
//  userVisibleOnly: true
}).then(function(sub) {
  console.log('endpoint:', sub.endpoint);
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log('Registration Failed',e);
});
```

But unable to get it work. Please let me know whether FCM provides support for Tizen Web application as I have seen FCM provider has given access for Android, iOS, and Javascript. But nowhere I saw support for Tizen Web application(Hybrid application for Wearable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tizen Web application **does not support service worker**. The FCM JavaScript API requires service worker support.

You can try this simple code snippet to check service worker support.

```
 if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) 
    alert('Service worker is Supported'); 
 else 
    alert('Service worker is not Supported');
```

I've tried the code snippet on Firefox, Chrome 
(Shortcut: Developer tools > Console > Paste the Code > Enter).

Both Supports service worker. But when I added this code chunk on js file of a Tizen web application it alerts 'not supported'.

The code sample to Register a service worker on Google developers also includes this check service worker API availability first before registration.

[Register a service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers#register_a_service_worker)

And about Native Mobile environment instead of Web, FCM supports Android and iOS Native environment, But not Tizen Native.

Comment: I have checked today on 3.0 emulator and it says it supports.